# Codeigniter returns Null from database a field which is not null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to return some data from my database with Codeigniter. The query is a join from all related tables.
Here is teh diagram:
[image]

The join query from the model:

```
public function combine_all_data_related($hostname){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('workstations w');
        $this->db->join('occupations o', 'w.occupation_id = o.occupation_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('departments d', 'd.department_id = o.department_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('workstation_configuration wc', 'wc.service_tag = w.service_tag', 'left');
        $this->db->join('workstation_models wm', 'wm.workstation_model_id = wc.workstation_model_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('workstation_types wt', 'wt.workstation_type_id = wm.workstation_type_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('users u', 'u.occupation_id = o.occupation_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('phone_numbers pn', 'pn.fmid = u.fmid', 'left');
        $this->db->join('phones p', 'p.phone_number_id = pn.phone_number_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('phone_brands pb', 'pb.phone_brand_id = p.phone_brand_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where("w.hostname = '" . $hostname . "'");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $return = $query->result();
    }
```

In the database, I have this record: 
[image]

And in-browser here are the var_dumps results SQL statement and returned data. The records that are not OK acquisition date, latest edit, and status.

[image]

Comment: Try this echo $this->db->last_query(); after $query statement

Comment: the first paragraph from the last image is the    print_r($this->db->last_query());

Comment: could you please give the sql dump, then we can identify

Comment: You have aquisition_date fields in workstations and phones tables, because phones table is joined later in the query, it's value overrides the first one, give different aliases to those fields.

Comment: please show the last sql dump.  It could be null because of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This looks like normal `LEFT JOIN` behavior when join conditions produce an empty result. Since pretty much everything is coming back as `NULL` the best guess is that the `ON` clause in your first join (`w.occupation_id = o.occupation_id`) is not producing any result

Answer (score 1):

You make `SELECT *` - select all columns from all specified tables. And in your tables some fields have the same names ('acquisition_date', 'latest_edit', 'status' - there are in 'phones' and 'workstations'). Therefore, you have an unpredictable result. Perhaps, phpmyadmin and Codeigniter use different drivers. In any case, using just `SELECT *` is very unreliable.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Instead of `$this->db->select('*');` use `$this->db->select('explicitly list all need fields', NULL);`.

For example:

```
$this->db->select('w.hostname ..., w.acquisition_date AS ws_acquisition_date ..., o.occupation_id ..., p.acquisition_date AS ph_acquisition_date ...', NULL);
```

Or at least for the fields of the same name in the request to explicitly specify the name-aliases:

```
$this->db->select('*, w.acquisition_date AS ws_acquisition_date, p.acquisition_date AS ph_acquisition_date, w.status AS ws_status, w.latest_edit AS ws_latest_edit, p.latest_edit AS ph_latest_edit', NULL);
```

And in PHP, refer to these fields as:

```
$return->ws_acquisition_date
$return->ph_acquisition_date
$return->ws_status
...
```

2. Or rename the fields so that the names do not repeat.

I recommend the first solution.